# Detect collision between ShapeRenderer line and sprite in LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm developing a simple game in which I need to detect collision between objects, I already know how to detect collision between 2 sprites, but now I need to detect collision between a sprite an a line drawn using the `ShapeRenderer` technique. Let's say I have a sprite defined like this:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(myPath);
TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture, w, h);
```

and a line like this:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Is there a way to detect when those 2 two objects collide?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how you're detecting your sprite collisions, I'd suggest a couple of different options that may work.

1. If you're using box2d for your current collision detection, and you don't have many lines to render with the shapeRenderer, you could consider creating a body/fixture to represent the line, make it a sensor and use the contact listener like you do for other bodies.
2. Or perhaps a more simplistic approach may be to use libgdx's Intersector class and poke around there for methods that may help you. For instance,

   public static boolean intersectLinePolygon(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Polygon polygon)

may work for you, where p1 is your (x1,y1), p2 is your (x2, y2) and polygon maps to your textureRegion.

Comment: I absolutely support the answer above. Since the ShapeRenderer is just a visual thing, like also a SpriteBatch is, you will definitely have to back your collision objects in the background somehow. Then you will not have to render a line at all. I think there was also an intersection method for intersecting two polygons at the same time!